# How to set view's height responsive?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, responsive-design

I have 2 static views: Headline and Bottom navigator (as mentioned in the attached visualization) with 3 rem and 3.5 rem height respectively, and I want to put a responsive view between them (the light blue area). The responsive view is supposed to include list views of elements (green ones) with scroll view.
I have 2 questions:

1. How can I make the green view responsive as being between two static views? is there any way to calculate its height in a way that it would be the same on different screens?
2. Every green element is 7 rem in height. How can I display different amounts of (complete) elements in different screens as the maximum as possible according to the wrapper view's height? I mean that I don't want that some kind of screen will cut an element between scrolls..

I tried to give percentage height for the top and bottom views but I want their height to be static.

[image: visualization]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This is a component that I used for a recent application; feel free to modify it to suit your needs. Hopefully, this will help you find the right answer. 

    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import { View, Text, ScrollView, Dimensions } from "react-native";
    
    const HeightComponent  = () => {
      const [wrapperHeight, setWrapperHeight] = useState(0);
    
      const calculateGreenViewHeight = () => {
        const headlineHeight = 3; // in rem
        const bottomNavigatorHeight = 3.5; // in rem
        const screenHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;
        const availableHeight = screenHeight - (headlineHeight + bottomNavigatorHeight) * 16; // Convert rem to pixels (16 pixels per rem)
        return Math.floor(availableHeight / 7) * 7; // Adjust the height to be a multiple of 7 rem
      };
    
      const handleWrapperLayout = (event) => {
        const height = event.nativeEvent.layout.height;
        setWrapperHeight(height);
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        // Calculate the initial height once the component is mounted
        const initialGreenViewHeight = calculateGreenViewHeight();
        // Use initialGreenViewHeight to determine the initial number of green elements to display
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }} onLayout={handleWrapperLayout}>
          <View
            style={{
              height: 3 * 16,
              backgroundColor: "lightgray",
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
          >
            <Text>Headline</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ height: wrapperHeight, backgroundColor: "lightblue" }}>
            <ScrollView>
              {/* Render green elements dynamically based on the calculated height */}
              {Array.from({ length: Math.floor(wrapperHeight / (7 * 16)) }).map(
                (_, index) => (
                  <View
                    key={index}
                    style={{
                      height: 7 * 16,
                      backgroundColor: "lightgreen",
                      margin: 10,
                    }}
                  >
                    <Text>{`Element ${index + 1}`}</Text>
                  </View>
                )
              )}
            </ScrollView>
          </View>
          <View
            style={{
              height: 3.5 * 16,
              backgroundColor: "lightgray",
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
          >
            <Text>Bottom Navigator</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    };
    
    export default HeightComponent;
```

Comment: I'm happy that the solution that I gave is fulfilling your needs.

Answer (score 0):

you can try working with "vh" instead of rem for a more responsive design
you can also add a min or max height based on your needs so the elements won't take more than the desired height

Answer (score 0):

Hi take a look on this package, normally I use this to make the apps responsive:

you can make anything responsive with this:

https://github.com/marudy/react-native-responsive-screen

I hope this can helps.